# A python program that fetches response data from ajax website?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, scrapy

Kindly note that I am new to programming. These are the problems I encountered when learning web scraping using python.
The web site I used was https://www.mobikwik.com/ (online recharge and payment site for mobile, dth, electricity bills)
But all I get is a 403 response when scraping. Then I understood that this might be because the website is using ajax. My objective when making the program was to receive user input for mobile number and then pass the value in the mobile operator search in the website, the page loads up the current Operator and circle, which I want to display in my program. The python phonenumber module is useless if the mobile number is ported to another operator. Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried printing out the content of the response (`response.content()`)?

Comment: The server is telling you no.  I would suggest trying to use `selenium` to achieve your desired goals.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark I will try that. Thank you.

Comment: @Chris thank you

Comment: @Chris I tried selenium but it gives me errors. I tried all method in find_element() but it brings up error. when using find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'input') the is_displayed() gives response false and is_enabled() gives true.

Comment: @CyberNoob - Without any clues, and by that I mean code and/or error messages, it is almost impossible to understand or reproduce a behaviour. please improve your question and add some more context, would be great - Thanks  -- Read also: How to create [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two xhr requests and I'm not sure which of these you wanted so I did them both. All you need is to recreate the requests.

1. `getconnectiondetails`:

```py
scrapy shell

In [1]: phone_number = '9820123456'

In [2]: url = 'https://rapi.mobikwik.com/recharge/infobip/getconnectiondetails?cn='

In [3]: headers = {
   ...: "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
   ...: "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
   ...: "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
   ...: "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
   ...: "Connection": "keep-alive",
   ...: "DNT": "1",
   ...: "Host": "rapi.mobikwik.com",
   ...: "Origin": "https://www.mobikwik.com",
   ...: "Pragma": "no-cache",
   ...: "Referer": "https://www.mobikwik.com/",
   ...: "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
   ...: "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
   ...: "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-site",
   ...: "Sec-GPC": "1",
   ...: "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.372
   ...: 9.169 Safari/537.36",
   ...: "X-MClient": "0"
   ...: }

In [4]: req = scrapy.Request(url=url+phone_number, headers=headers)

In [5]: fetch(req)
[scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://rapi.mobikwik.com/recharge/infobip/getconnectiondetails?cn=9820123456> (referer: https://www.mobikwik.com/)

In [6]: json_data = response.json()

In [7]: json_data['data']['operatorId']
Out[7]: 338

In [8]: json_data['data']['circleId']
Out[8]: 15
```

2. `recommendedplans`:

```py
scrapy shell

In [1]: phone_number = '9820123456'

In [2]: url = 'https://rapi.mobikwik.com/recharge/v1/rechargePlansAPI/recommendedplans/338/15?cn='

In [3]: headers = {
   ...: "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
   ...: "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
   ...: "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
   ...: "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
   ...: "Connection": "keep-alive",
   ...: "DNT": "1",
   ...: "Host": "rapi.mobikwik.com",
   ...: "Origin": "https://www.mobikwik.com",
   ...: "Pragma": "no-cache",
   ...: "Referer": "https://www.mobikwik.com/",
   ...: "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
   ...: "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
   ...: "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-site",
   ...: "Sec-GPC": "1",
   ...: "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.372
   ...: 9.169 Safari/537.36",
   ...: "X-MClient": "0"
   ...: }

In [4]: req = scrapy.Request(url=url+phone_number, headers=headers)

In [5]: fetch(req)
[scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://rapi.mobikwik.com/recharge/v1/rechargePlansAPI/recommendedplans/338/15?cn=9820123456> (referer: https://www.mobikwik.com/)

In [6]: json_data = response.json()

In [7]: for item in json_data['data']['plans']:
   ...:     print(item['id'])
   ...:
1104293
1155779
1155937
1164885
1156067
```

Comment: The first plan was what i needed. I tried header using user agent and referer but didn't get any response. Thankyou that was really helpful and broadened my horizon. Perhaps you might have noticed that the website displays proper operator names and circle names than there numbers. Is there a way to get what's displayed on the screen than the corresponding numbers? Thankyou

Comment: No there is no operator name.

Comment: Sir, just visit https://www.mobikwik.com/ and enter any Indian number. They will give you the the current operator and the circle under which the sim is active.

Comment: I meant that there's no operator name in the API, just the id.

Comment: Yes there's no operator name in the API, i think they are referencing it with numbers. Is there a way to capture the operator name and circle from the website as it displays.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I solved the issue with the operator. This was the first time I am using requests. I didn't know that I had to use all the details under header. Thank You for your help and support.